# How to find url for developed page (Confluence) in Python

Tags: python, url, confluence

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

# Request body
data = {
    'type': 'page',
    'title': page_title,
    'ancestors': [{'id':parent_page_id}],
    'space': {'key':space_key},
    'body': {
        'storage':{
            'value': page_html,
            'representation':'storage',
        }
    }
}

# We're ready to call the api
try:

    r = requests.post(url=url, data=json.dumps(data),auth = (user, password), headers=headers,verify=False)

    # Consider any status other than 2xx an error
    if not r.status_code // 100 == 2:
        print("Error: Unexpected response {}".format(r))
    else:
        print('Page Created!')
        print(r.url)

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:

    # A serious problem happened, like an SSLError or InvalidURL
    print("Error: {}".format(e))
```

After this confluence page is created and how to find the url for that page in the code itself?